# Wicket panel component doesnt recognize newlines

Tags: java, wicket, panel

Im new to wicket. Why doesn't /n add a new line to a string in a panel component? the /n just gets left out and the string continues as normal.

Comment: First of all: it is a `\n`, not a `/n`. A `/n` would be rendered properly. Second of all, a `Panel` component doesn't render strings directly, but a `Label` component does. If you want to render multi-line text, use a `MultiLineLabel` instead, which has proper support for new lines, paragraphs etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because its rendered as HTML and HTML does not recognize `\n` as new lines. Instead it is treated as a normal white space.

If you want a new line, insert a `<br>` into your string and use `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` on your component.

Answer (score 9):

Or if your component is a label, you can consider using [`MultiLineLabel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/MultiLineLabel.html)